# NPMJS Forever and Logfiles

Tags: node.js

Does Forever always have its own log file?  I have the following process running:

```
data:        uid            command       script                   forever pid   id logfile                    uptime
data:    [0] staff-intranet /usr/bin/node staff-intranet-server.js 24123   26733    /root/.forever/logfile.txt 0:0:10:47.967
```

However, my config file looks like this:

```
// Staff Intranet Configuration File
{
    "uid": "staff-intranet",
    "append": true,
    "script": "staff-intranet-server.js",
    "sourceDir": "/path/to/file/staff-intranet",
    "outFile": "/path/to/file/staff-intranet/output.txt",
    "errFile": "/path/to/file/staff-intranet/errors.txt",
    "logFile": "/path/to/file/staff-intranet/logs.txt"
}
```

But the logfile is still stored list as being stored in `/root/.forever/logfile.txt`.  Why is it not being stored in `/path/to/file/staff-intranet/logs.txt`?

Answer (score -1):

You can put:

```
-p /path/to/file/staff-intranet/
```

to put base path for all forever related files (pid files, etc.)